# Sequence a List[JsResult[A]] to a JsResult[List[A]]

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, play-json

I am attempting to make an API for stripe which involves a lot of mapping from Json to case classes (and vice versa). I have come across an issue where I end up with a `List[JsResult[A]]` (this is the result of mapping through a list of JObject's and doing some operations on them to map them to the appropriate case class). The code in question is below

```
case class Sources(data: List[PaymentSource],
                     hasMore: Boolean,
                     totalCount: Double,
                     url: String)

  implicit val sourcesReader: Reads[Sources] = {

    val dataAsList = (__ \ "data").read[List[JsObject]].flatMap{jsObjects =>
      val `jsResults` = jsObjects.map{jsObject =>
        val `type` = jsObject \ "type"

        val paymentSource: JsResult[PaymentSource] = `type` match {
          case JsString("card") =>
            Json.fromJson[Card](jsObject)
          case JsString("bitcoin_receiver") =>
            Json.fromJson[BitcoinReceiver](jsObject)
          case JsString(s) =>
            throw UnknownPaymentSource(s)
          case _ =>
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected a Json Object")
        }

        paymentSource
      }

      jsResults

    }
```

The jsResults has a type of `List[JsResult[A]]`, however to compose it properly with the reads we need to return either a `JsResult[A]` or a `JsError`.

Although its possible to do `Json.fromJson[Card](jsObject).get` instead of `Json.fromJson[Card](jsObject)`, doing so means we lose the accumulative error handling in Play Json (it also means we are pushing the errors into runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can't turn a `List[JsResult[A]]` into `JsResult[A]`, because what if you have multiple success results?  That would mean you have multiple values for `A`.  You *can* turn it into `JsResult[List[A]]`, there are a few ways to do this, I'd probably do this:

```
val allErrors = jsResults.collect {
  case JsError(errors) => errors
}.flatten

val jsResult = if (allErrors.nonEmpty) {
  JsError(allErrors)
} else {
  JsSuccess(jsResults.collect {
    case JsSuccess(a, _) => a
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `Reads.list()`.

```
val paymentSourceReader: Reads[PaymentSource] = __.read[JsObject].flatMap { o =>
  (__ \ "type").read[String].collect(ValidationError("UnknownPaymentSource")) {
    case "card" =>
      o.as[Card]
    case "bitcoin_receiver" =>
      o.as[BitcoinReceiver]
  }
}
```

1. `read[String]` create error if no `type` pproperty.
2. `collect(ValidationError("UnknownPaymentSource")` create error if
   type !(card|bitcoin_receiver).
3. `o.as[...]` throw exception if can not cast

then use `paymentSourceReader'

```
val dataReader: Reads[List[PaymentSource]] = (__ \ "data").read[List[PaymentSource]](Reads.list(paymentSourceReader))
```

`dataReader` may be used in complex reader `Reads[PaymentSource]` with combinators for `Sources` or `json.reads(dataReader)` for `JsResult[List[PaymentSource]]`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to join two JsResults into on JsSuccess. `tupled` and `and` helped me to fulfill this task. Both are part of the `play.api.libs.functional` package.

This is how you can join two `JsResult` into one:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

((__ \ 'id).validate[Long] and (__ \ 'name).validate[String]).tupled 
    match {
      case JsSuccess((id,name),_) => ...
      case err: JsError =>
```